# Ubuntu no sound + no Bluetooth pairing (two separate issues, may be related)

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

About two weeks ago my sound suddenly stopped working. I have already tried half of the first page of Google "ubuntu no sound" results and I still can't fix it.

I tried using my cellphone as an audio device to at least be able to attend quarantine video classes, but I can't even pair my laptop with any Bluetooth device, so I am very screwed.

Laptop model: **Dell Inspiron 15 7000**

Sound: **alsa-base audio**

Bluetooth? It pairs to the device for like 2 seconds, then disconnects, some times it won't pair at all. My android detects it, but it just disconnects.

Headset working? No, I can't reproduce audio in any way or form, except by connecting it do the TV with HDMI, but the sound comes from the TV, not from my laptop.

Ubuntu version: **18.04**

What have I already tried?

Pretty much 3/4 of the first Google search for "Ubuntu no sound"

Bluetooth and audio stopped working at the same time (related?)

Is it muted? No

Does the sound icon appear? Yes, and I can still manipulate the audio, but obviously nothing happens

Have you tried opening alsa mixer and unmuting everything? yes